# PHP date returning blank for Year "2090" with strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have `PHP version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10`.

I am specifying date as "2090-11-29 05:00:00" and using `strotime` to print and compare it with Current date. But it returns "Blank Value"

Here is my Code :

```
<?php
    $dateTime = "2003-04-19 11:00:00";
    $mdate = strtotime($dateTime);
    $ndateTime = "2090-11-29 05:00:00";
    $ndate = strtotime($ndateTime);

    echo $ndate.' - <br />';

    if(($date > $mdate) && ($date < $ndate)) {
        echo $date.' is greater than  '.$ndate . ' First ';
    } else {
        echo $ndate.' is greater than  '.$date;
    }

    echo '<br />';
    echo phpversion();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the max date you can get is 2038, check the  [year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) for more information about this issue.
Now to solve the problem -- as @Mike suggested -- you can use DateTime objects, consider the following example:

```
$date =new DateTime("2090-11-29 05:00:00");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //will output 2090-11-29 05:00:00
```

and you can set the format as you wish and there are enough examples found in the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)
Also [settimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) function for datetime object

Comment: Note, this problem only exists for 32 bit systems. See the [strtotime() manual](http://php.net/strtotime). Also, you haven't really provided a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Mike you are right, using Datetime objects solves this issue, I'll update for that. thnks

Comment: @WesleyMurch - that's the output of my fiddle, my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime), which supports bigger dates than the regular time functions on 32-bit machines; its constructor supports the same format as `strtotime()` so conversion should be straightforward.

However, in this case a simple string comparison will accomplish the same thing, because the `Y-m-d H:i:s` format is suitable for comparisons of dates until Y10k.

```
$mdateTime = "2003-04-19 11:00:00";
$ndateTime = "2090-11-29 05:00:00";
$date = '2013-03-11';

if ($date > $mdateTime && $date < $ndateTime) {
    // $date is between $mdateTime and $ndateTime
} else {
    echo $ndate.' is greater than  '.$date;
}
```